# AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'Map'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, folium

I tried every possible solution on this website and others like making sure there is no other file named folium.py on my device, reinstalled everything 2 times and I am still getting this error when trying to create a map with m = folium.Map() function. Please help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with `folium`, but a quick glance at the docs suggest that it's supposed to be a lowercase "m". As in, change your code to `m = folium.map()`.

Comment: @mypetlion that's a subpackage (forgive my terminology), not the Map class. `folium.Map()` is correct: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.folium.Map

Edit: @Onur Balcı Please check if you happen to have a file named "folium.py" in your working directory

Comment: @MCO yes I have it in AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\folium

Comment: @Onur Balcı i meant if you have a file called folium.py in your script's directory. if that is the case, python would import that file (which doesn't have a `Map` class) instead of the folium module.

Comment: @MCO no I don't